# Connect Gmail to CiviMail?

Tags: civimail

Is there a way to to do this without multiple layers of installation on multiple computers (this would be intended for 4-5 staff members regularly using Civi for donor outreach).

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This looks like a good question.  You could make it even better by editing it to provide more details about exactly what you are trying to do.  This will help people provide better answers.

Comment: Please explain with more detail what the outcomes are that you need

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve here, but there are a number of extensions that link CiviCRM to Gmail.  Have you looked at the following any of the following?

- [CiviGmail Integration With Gmail](https://civicrm.org/blog/deepaksrivastava/civigmail-integration-with-gmail)
- [Leveraging CiviCRM Email-to-Activity Processing in Gmail](https://civicrm.org/blog/dahndy/leveraging-civicrm-email-to-activity-processing-in-gmail)
- [Google Apps Sync](https://civicrm.org/extensions/google-apps-sync)